# Running a batch file in relative path?

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file, relative-path

There is a batch file which I want to run it when I press the button.
My code works fine when I use absolute (full) path. But using relative path causes to occur an exception.
This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //x64
    System.Diagnostics.Process batchFile_1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    batchFile_1.StartInfo.FileName = @"..\myBatchFiles\BAT1\f1.bat";
    batchFile_1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @".\myBatchFiles\BAT1"; 
    batchFile_1.Start();
}
```

and the raised exception:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

The directory of the batch file is:

```
C:\Users\GntS\myProject\bin\x64\Release\myBatchFiles\BAT1\f1.bat
```

The output `.exe` file is located in:

```
C:\Users\GntS\myProject\bin\x64\Release
```

I searched and none of the results helped me. What is the correct way to run a batch file in relative path?!

Comment: You can get executable path, see: [HOW TO: Determine the Executing Application's Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx)

Comment: @MaciejLos Yes, I can. But what about ..\\ or .\\ ? I always used them successfully.

Comment: According to the documentation, if `UseShellExecute` is true (and that's the default value), then the executable is searched relatively to the working directory. Which means that you're trying to execute `.\myBatchFiles\BAT1\..\myBatchFiles\BAT1\f1.bat`, which would resolve to `C:\Users\GntS\myProject\bin\x64\Release\myBatchFiles\myBatchFiles\BAT1\f1.bat` (notice the two `myBatchFiles`)

Comment: Well, there's no default working directory of process. So, you have to provide complete path. On the other side, using `..\`  or  `.\` in batch file is OK, but not in .Net.

Comment: @KevinGosse I am confused. What is working directory in my case? Did you mean it is not always particular?

Comment: @KevinGosse As I remember I assumed the current path is the `.exe` file path and I used ../ or ./  successfully!!! I need to study more!

Comment: @MaciejLos If I obtain the `.exe` file path, then how can I address my batch file relative to the `.exe` file path?

Comment: Use [GetDirectoryName method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to *JeffRSon*`s answer and comments by *MaciejLos* and *KevinGosse* my problem was solved as below:

```
string executingAppPath = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;

 batchFile_1.StartInfo.FileName = executingAppPath.Substring(0, executingAppPath.LastIndexOf('\\')) + "\\myBatchFiles\\BAT1\\f1.bat";
 batchFile_1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = executingAppPath.Substring(0, executingAppPath.LastIndexOf('\\')) + "\\myBatchFiles\\BAT1";
```

An alternative way is:

```
string executingAppPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
batchFile_1.StartInfo.FileName = executingAppPath.Substring(6) + "\\myBatchFiles\\BAT1\\f1.bat";
batchFile_1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = executingAppPath.Substring(6) + "\\myBatchFiles\\BAT1";
```

I report it here hoping help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

The batch file would be relative to the working directory (i.e. f1.bat)

However, your working directory should be an absolute path. It is not guaranteed whichever path is current for your application (may be set in .lnk). In particular it's not the exe path.

Sou you should use the path of your exe file as obtained from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory (or any other well known method) to build the path of your batch file and/or working directory.

Finally - use Path.Combine to determine a correctly formatted path.